# How do i send the Hindi text to php server by using HttpUrlConnection in Android

Tags: php, android

I'm developing an Android application in which the user can register by choosing Hindi and English language. It is working fine while sending in English but while sending the hindi text I'm getting unknown format text `%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%97` in the table.I have tried to put encoding for the header but it is not working.

The code which I'm using

```
URL url = new URL(Config.ORGANISATION_DETAILS_URL);

// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary=" + boundary);

// conn.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

//Adding Parameter name of organisation
String str=nameoforget.getText().toString();
String nameoforg=URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
//String nameoforg=str;
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"nameoforg\"" + lineEnd); 
//dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
//dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + nameoforg.length() + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(nameoforg); // mobile_no is String variable
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

String noofstudents=""+noofstdset.getText().toString();
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"noofstudents\"" + lineEnd); 
//dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
//dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + noofstudents.length() + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(noofstudents); // mobile_no is String variable
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

/*To upload file*/ 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
if(sourceFileUri!=null)
{
    // create a buffer of  maximum size
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
    }
}
// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: That seems like quite a lot of code. Can you edit your question to only include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? Assume that the set of people who can answer your question are a subset of the people who don't have time to read through more than about 10 lines of code.

Comment: What's collations of your table in MySql where you save data from android ?

Comment: Hi Wai Ha Lee Thanks for your reply and I am new to this site. Now my doubt is I want to send the Hindi text to Php file using HttpURLconnection. Before sending I am decoding with URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8") even though it is showing like this "%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%97".

Comment: Hi eurosecom my issue is before storing data in database I mean when I try to send Hindi text from Android to Php in Php itself the Hindi text coming like this "%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%97". How would i send the Hindi data?

Answer (score 1):

**How to send Hindi Text or other Encoded Text to Php Server using HttpUrlConnection in Android**

```
    After searching in google i got the solution for my question. Before sending the data I Encoded the String with URLEncoder.encode() in java class. The following code is in java
```

**In Java:**

```
     String nameoforg=URLEncoder.encode("हिन्दी", "UTF-8");
     dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"nameoforg\"" +  lineEnd); 
     dos.writeBytes(nameoforg); 
     dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
```

And now in PHP when we receive the Post data from Android we need to decode the post data.For example

**In Php:**

```
    $nameoforg=$_POST['nameoforg'];
    $nameoforg=urldecode($nameoforg);
    echo $nameoforg;
```

That's it...now you can store the same data in database from php.

Answer (score 0):

### To display hindi language

Call this method while hitting sever

```
encodeString(your hindi or english string)

public static String encodeString(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  return URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-16");
}
```

Call this method after getting response from sever

```
decodeString(your server string)

public static String decodeString(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-16");
}
```